# How to regex replace a string with matches in purely scripting, not reading from buffer

Tags: regular-expressions, replace-regexp-in-string

I'm a beginner in Emacs and Elisp, but do have programming experience.

My question is quite straightforward, I want to have a command `open-git` that when in a git directory, it opens the url inside a browser.

I have the following code

```lisp
(defun open-git ()
  "Opens the git repository in a browser."
  (interactive)
  (browse-url (replace-regexp-in-string
               "git@\\(.*\\):\\(.*\\)/\\(.*\\).git", ; Regex
                "https://\\1/\\2/\\3.git/", ; Replacement
                (shell-command-to-string "git remote get-url origin")) ; String
              )
  )
```

The git repository url is in a ssh format, meaning for `browse-url` to work correctly, I have to regex replace it.
I have used `M-x regexp-builder` to confirm it matches correctly. However, when trying to execute the command from a file buffer, it gives me the error `Symbol's function definition is void: \,`.
Reading up on it, I saw that `\,` is used to run regex interactively for the replacement. But I'm not using `\,`, is it being used internally?

On a git url that is for example `git@github.com:foo/bar.git` the matches are:

1. github.com
2. foo
3. bar

Obviously I can just set the git url to the https version and be done with it. But I also just want to understand Emacs and Elisp better, so figured this was a nice easy exercise.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the commas after the regex and the replacement

```el
(defun open-git ()
  "Opens the git repository in a browser."
  (interactive)
  (browse-url (replace-regexp-in-string
               "git@\\(.*\\):\\(.*\\)/\\(.*\\).git" ; Regex
                "https://\\1/\\2/\\3.git/" ; Replacement
                (shell-command-to-string "git remote get-url origin")))) ; String
```

Comment: OML, was that the issue? Thank you so much! I would expect Flycheck or similar to highlight it as a syntax issue.

Comment: Commas are valid syntax in elisp, but not for separating list items.  The byte-compiler *does* complain about your original code: "Warning: the function ‘,’ is not known to be defined." (which makes sense if you understand that the lisp reader is producing the likes of `(\, "https://\\1/\\2/\\3.git/")` from your code (which in turn is because of the way that commas are *expected* to be used, within backquoted forms).

Comment: N.b. The interactive regexp replacement case (introduced in Emacs 22.1) is something different -- for that case `\,` was simply selected as the syntax for evaluating the following expression as lisp code in order to be a syntactic analogue of the pre-existing use of a comma for evaluating the following expression within a backquoted form (with the latter being what you were effectively running into here).

Comment: Your take-away is probably that if you *ever* see errors mentioning commas, the *first* thing to do is check whether you've accidentally used them as list separators :)

Comment: I suppose my experience with other languages is what was my downfall with this, I will keep in mind that lists should not be separated with commas in lisp